# how to deal with product-type nonlineariteies in PDEs

Tags: reference-request, finite-element-method

I am trying to work on some finite element method to solve a diffusion PDE like Fisher equation [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_equation) or something like reaction diffusion. Let us take Fisher for example
$$
\partial_t u = \Delta u + u(1-u).
$$
By assuming $u$ as a linear combination of basis functions $\phi_i$, let us say Lagrange P1 element,
$$
u(t,x) = \sum_{i=1}^N u_i^t \phi_i(x)
$$

how does one deal with terms like $u(t,x)^2$ ? It seems clear that one cannot simply take  $u(t,x)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^N (u_i^t)^2 \phi_i(x)$, since this expression is true only in the nodal points of the basis functions, but not everywhere else.

Also, more in general, how does one deal with similar issues like

- $u(t,x)^\gamma$ with $\gamma$ possibly fractional
- $f(x)u(t,x)$ where $f$ is as well a as an element of $span(\phi_i)_{i=1,\dots,N}$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use some quadrature rules to integrate $\int_T \phi_i (u(x))^2\ dx$. Then you should end up with a finite-dimensional nonlinear equation.

When solving that equation by e.g. Newton method, make sure that you take the Jacobian of the discretized equation (and not discretize a linearized equation).